# Proxy caching WordPress with Nginx

Tags: nginx

I will Elaborate more :

I want to know how can i configure my nNginx serve to use the Proxy caching for my 
 wordpress.
 I readed in a [guide](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/caching/) that the Proxy caching of Nginx is that powerfull that if you enable it
 you wont need use any other wordpress caching plugin.

So that s why i m here. I wanna know how can i configure my Nginx to use proxy caching.

Thank ou

Comment: That's a server question, and you might have better luck at stackoverflow.com.

Comment: k i ll go there ty

Comment: Could you elaborate on what nginx feature you mean? What had you tried? As far as I remember WP Codex documentation had some examples of nginx configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend starting with the [Codex Nginx](https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx) as mentioned by @Rarst. These two additional links may also provide more guidance on what you're trying to accomplish.

- [How-to: Nginx as a front-end proxy cache for WordPress](https://vip.wordpress.com/2010/02/01/how-to-nginx-as-a-front-end-proxy-cache-for-wordpress/)
- [Nginx Reverse Cache Proxy](https://www.codementor.io/devops/tutorial/devops-tutorial-nginx-reverse-proxy)